# How to add line not connected in a sequence using leaflet

Tags: r, dictionary, leaflet

It seems `polyline` will connect all the start end points in sequence together like an unfilled polygon. Is there a way to add each line separately on an interactive map in R?

This earlier thread proposed a different [package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31311063/how-to-add-polylines-from-one-location-to-others-separately-using-leaflet-in-shi), but could I do this with the `leaflet` package?

Comment: The package mentioned in the post you link to will produce a **leaflet** map.

Comment: that looks more like a map view map though

Comment: The `@map` slot of a **mapview** object is of class `leaflet` so it is a **leaflet** map in that respect. The look is just a result of the **leaflet** setup in **mapview** (the defaults). Regarding your question I suggest you first familiarise yourself with the spatial classes from **sp**. Plotting is easy once you have a valid set of lines. See my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38026173/how-different-colors-to-different-sections-of-a-route-on-leaflet-map-r-studio which seems related to your endeavor.