# How different colors to different sections of a route on leaflet map? [R Studio]

Tags: json, r, dictionary, routes, leaflet

I have a JSON file of a long route. The file contains the lat and long of of this route.

I'm trying to mark different sections of this route based on a set of criteria (which I've compiled in a dataframe). However, I'm facing to problems:

1) How do I break up this long set of lat and longs into segments? (can't do this manually because I have many route variations)

2) How do I assign a variable color to each segment?

I intend to use leaflet map (for its interactivity), but I'm open to better suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

When working with spatial data, it helps to know spatial classes! I am assuming you know hoe to read your JSON file as a data frame into R.

Here's a reproducible example:

```
library(mapview)
library(sp)

### create some random data with coordinates from (data("breweries91", package = "mapview"))
set.seed(123)
dat <- data.frame(val = as.integer(rnorm(32, 10, 2)),
                  lon = coordinates(breweries91)[, 1],
                  lat = coordinates(breweries91)[, 2])

### state condition for creation of lines
cond <- c(8, 9, 10)

### loop through conditions and create a SpatialLines object for each condition
lns <- lapply(seq(cond), function(i) {

  ind <- dat$val == cond[i]
  sub_dat <- dat[ind, ]

  coords <- cbind(sub_dat$lon, sub_dat$lat)
  ln <- coords2Lines(coords, ID = as.character(cond[i]))

  proj4string(ln) <- "+init=epsg:4326"
  return(ln)
})

### view lines with mapview
mapview(lns[[1]], col = "darkred") +
  mapview(lns[[2]], col = "forestgreen") +
  mapview(lns[[3]], col = "cornflowerblue")
```

Essentially, what we are doing here is create a valid sp::SpatialLines object for each condition we specify. The we plot those using **mapview** given you mentioned interactivity. Plotting of spatial objects can be achieved in many ways (**base**, **lattice**, **ggplot2**, **leaflet**, ...) so there's many options to choose. Have a look at [sp Gallery](https://edzer.github.io/sp/) for a nice tutorial.

**Note**: This answer is only valid for non-projected geographic coordinates (i.e. latitude/longitude)!

Comment: For those looking to reproduce this example you will need to have the leaflet library loaded to access `breweries91` (add `library(leaflet)` to the start of the script)

Comment: Also in the mapview call, "col" needs to be "color" because "col" now matches multiple arguments.